# Variadic template parameter in middle of parameter list

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to specify a function that takes a generic function as parameter. The function is defined like this:

```
template <typename TRet, typename... TsArgs>
using Fun = TRet (*)(TsArgs...);
```

How do I specify a generic function which takes that generic function as a parameter? I tried this:

```
template<typename TRet, typename... TsArgs, Fun<TRet, TsArgs...> F>
TRet wrap(TsArgs... args) {
  return F(args...);
}
```

To wrap this function:

```
bool foo(int x, double y) {
    return x < y;
}
```

Like this:

```
Fun<bool, int, double> func = wrap<bool, int, double, foo>;
```

However, this does not compile unfortunately. gcc 8.1 has the following error message:

```
<source>:16:35: error: no matches converting function 'wrap' to type 'Fun<bool, int, double>' {aka 'bool (*)(int, double)'}
     Fun<bool, int, double> func = wrap<bool, int, double, foo>;
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and clang 6 has the following error:

```
<source>:16:35: error: address of overloaded function 'wrap' does not match required type 'bool (int, double)'
    Fun<bool, int, double> func = wrap<bool, int, double, foo>;
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

However, if I replace the `TsArgs` with `int, double`, just as in the signature of `foo()`, it compiles just fine, letting me believe having those variadic template arguments in the middle of the parameter list don't work as I expected. How could I achieve my goal otherwise?

Here's the MCVE:

```
template <typename TRet, typename... TsArgs>
using Fun = TRet (*)(TsArgs...);

template<typename TRet, typename... TsArgs, Fun<TRet, TsArgs...> F>
TRet wrap(TsArgs... args) {
    return F(args...);
}

bool foo(int x, double y) {
    return x < y;
}

int main() {
    Fun<bool, int, double> func = wrap<bool, int, double, foo>;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your suspicions are correct. Variadic template parameters consume all parameters to the template, and pretty much cannot be deduced, if not explicitly specified in the function's signature. You have to find some other way to do what you want to do.

Comment: The best workaround I can think of is unrolling the variadic parameter for each number of function parameters. Do you know of anything better?

Comment: `template <auto F>` could be useful, except it will become a pain if you want to use a member of an overloaded function set as the template argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use C++17, you can use `auto` for template parameter.

This can simplify a lot my preceding answer.

Or better: simplify the use of the wrapper.

If you define a `wrapHelper` struct as follows

```
template <typename T, T>
struct wrapHelper;

template <typename TRet, typename... TsArgs, Fun<TRet, TsArgs...> F>
struct wrapHelper<Fun<TRet, TsArgs...>, F>
 {
   static TRet func (TsArgs ... args)
    { return F(args...); }
 };
```

you can write `wrapper`, using `auto`, as follows

```
template <auto X>
struct wrap : public wrapHelper<decltype(X), X>
 { };
```

This way there is no need to explicate the return type (`TRet`) and the arguments types (`TsArgs...`): they are deduced (in `wrapHelper`) from `foo`.

So, instead of

```
Fun<bool, int, double> func = wrap<bool, int, double>::func<foo>;
```

you have to write

```
Fun<bool, int, double> func = wrap<foo>::func;
```

or also

```
auto func = wrap<foo>::func;
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename TRet, typename... TsArgs>
using Fun = TRet (*)(TsArgs...);

bool foo(int x, double y)
 { return x < y; }

template <typename T, T>
struct wrapHelper;

template <typename TRet, typename... TsArgs, Fun<TRet, TsArgs...> F>
struct wrapHelper<Fun<TRet, TsArgs...>, F>
 {
   static TRet func (TsArgs ... args)
    { return F(args...); }
 };

template <auto X>
struct wrap : public wrapHelper<decltype(X), X>
 { };

int main()
 {   
   auto func { wrap<foo>::func };

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(func), Fun<bool, int, double>>{} );

   std::cout << func(1, 2.0) << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Looks great! I also added `template<auto X> decltype(X) wrap_func = wrap<X>::func;` so I can just use `wrap_func<foo>`. I was thinking the first solution could be simplified too by utilizing type deduction somehow, but I couldn't get it to work, so I suppose this is the best possible

Comment: @Felk - Yes, `wrap_func` seems to me a nice improvement. Anyway, about type deduction in first solution, I can't exclude it's possible (pre C++17) in a reasonable way. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can make `wrap` in two steps: (1) a template struct that recevive `TRet` and `TArgs...` template parameters and (2) a template static `func()` function that receive a `Fun<TRet, TsArgs...>` template parameter.

Something as follows

```
template <typename TRet, typename... TsArgs>
struct wrap
 {
   template <Fun<TRet, TsArgs...> F>
   static TRet func (TsArgs ... args)
    { return F(args...); }
 };
```

that you can use this way

```
Fun<bool, int, double> func = wrap<bool, int, double>::func<foo>;
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename TRet, typename... TsArgs>
using Fun = TRet (*)(TsArgs...);

template <typename TRet, typename... TsArgs>
struct wrap
 {
   template <Fun<TRet, TsArgs...> F>
   static TRet func (TsArgs ... args)
    { return F(args...); }
 };

bool foo(int x, double y)
 { return x < y; }

int main()
 {
   Fun<bool, int, double> func = wrap<bool, int, double>::func<foo>;

   std::cout << func(1, 2.0) << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: So simple, yet so genius. That'll do it. I will accept your answer after I implement your solution tomorrow

Comment: @Felk - Not so simple: in this way we have to explicit the `TRet` and `TsArgs...` types that are part of `foo()`. Unfortunately I don't know, pre C++17, how go around this problem. But if you can use C++17, it's can be done and the use of `wrap` become very simple. Added another answer with a C++17 solution.